# Use repository.clear() to clear two tables with ManyToOne

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Is there any ways to clear two tables connected with ManyToOne?

Table A

```
@Entity('table_A')
export class TableA{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  B_ID: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => TableB)
  tableB: TableB;

  @Column()
  userId: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  user: User;
}
```

Table B

```
@Entity('table_B')
export class TableB{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'time', type: 'text' })
  time: Date;

  @Column({ name: 'msgid', type: 'int', nullable: true })
  msgid: number;

  @Column({ name: 'event', type: 'text', nullable: true })
  event: string;
}
```

I can use `this.tableARepository.clear();`  to clear Table_A but when I run `this.tableBRepository.clear();`  Data in Table A restores.
Anyone have a clue on this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you set `onDelete: CASCADE`?

Comment: How should I set it?

Comment: What does the code you're using to call these methods look like? Are you calling them both from within a single transaction?

Comment: `this.tableARepository.clear();
this.tableBRepository.clear();`

Comment: check typeorm [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/relations/relation-options) for how to set `onDelete`

Comment: @AminTaghikhani Is this correct?
`@Column()
  notificationId: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => Notification, (notification) => {
    cascade: ['remove']
  })
  notification?: Notification;`

Comment: no, `@ManyToOne(() => Notification, (notification) => {     onDelete: 'CASCADE'  })`

Comment: @AminTaghikhani I've added this line of code but TableB still cannot be cleared. It showed UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. Can I check which constraint is violated?